# How to calculate a shape based on movement using opencv or other open source lib?

Tags: image, opencv

Here is the original image, the green colour is the background, and blue is the shape.

[image]

If my eye go closer to the shape, the blue square will be bigger like this:

[image]

If my eye go left, the shape will work like this:

[image]

I already know my eyes movement position, but how can I calculate what will the shape change? Any recommends? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need know the camera matrix http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix it will define the way which 3D coord will be projected to your sreen coordinates. If you know orientation of your camera, then you know 3d coords of object points relative to camera. Applying camera matrix transform to these 3d coords will give you 2d projections in you screen coordinates.